# Some SD cards fail to write (CMD24 returns CRC error)

Tags: pic, sd-card

I'm using a PIC18 to write to SD cards via SPI.  For many cards, this is working file BUT for some cards I pass the init process but when trying to write to the card, CMD24 returns 0x05 (which I believe is a CRC error)

```
// send CMD24 - preparing for a 512 byte block
SD_command(CMD24, 0x0001, CMD24_CRC);
    
// read response
res1 = SD_readRes1();  //This returns 0x05 for some cards!
```

I have used CMD59 - CRC_ON_OFF with parameter 0x00 to turn of CRC, and the command seems to complete. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I read a comment of someone on a forum, who spent one week looking for an error in this code. In his case, he found that with some sd cards, he has to put a valid crc in the sd command, whatever the state of crc check option (cmd59).
Maybe it is simpler to put a valid crc in all cases.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, I did try to do this, but could not find code to calculate the CRC for data commands, as all the example libraries use pre-calculated CRCs for the initial commands and then ignore CRC for read/write operations, as they are supposed to be turned off.  Do you have any example code to calculate the SD CRCs?